# Twilio functions: press intercom key

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

Im trying learn Twilio by making a practical simple app.
I have a phone number setup to Twilio Studio flow.

The flow will execute a Runtime Function.

I'm trying to make it so that the function will press the number "9" key.

The idea is that this function will press the key to my apartment buzzer.

I figured this would be easy, but I cannot find any documentation on how to set the function to press the key.
Any help would be appreciated!

This is my code so far:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    twiml.play("9"); // this returns an error
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the  using the digits attribute.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#attributes-digits